# Need Help to write sample Unix script to perform division of 2 commands output

Tags: scripting, ksh

Can somebody please help me to write a KSH script to calculate the percentage of memory used in AIX server?

Here are my requirements

1. I want my script to execute the svmon -G command and my script should cut the first 2 values
2. My script should divide 3rd value by 1st value and result should be multiplied by 100 to get percentage of the memory used.

Below is the sample script which has already been written.

```
#!bin/ksh
echo $(
    svmon -G | grep memory | 
        sed 's/  */ /g' | 
        cut -d" " -f 3
)/$(
    svmon -G | grep memory | 
        sed 's/  */ /g' | 
        cut -d" " -f 2
)
```

I am getting below Output

```
4915483/ 7864320
```

But I need the result of the division operation as output

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code request. If you want to hire a programmer you might want to take a look at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Pipe the output of your command into the `bc` command. Make sure you set the `scale` option to sufficient number of digits.

Comment: `cut -f 2` and `cut -f 3` do not appear consistent with the request to *divide 3rd value by 1st value*.  Which one is correct, the code (2 and 3) or the text (1 and 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the result of your command and pipe it into `bc` :

```
echo "scale=16; 4915483/ 7864320" | bc
```

This results in

```
.6250359853108723
```

So in your case the following should work (**edited to show multiplication by 100**):

```
echo "scale=16; 100 * " $(svmon -G | grep memory | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f 3)/$(svmon -G | grep memory | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f 2) | bc
```

I have added `100 *` after the `scale=16;` so you get the result multiplied by 100.

You can change the `scale` factor to change the number of significant digits in the division (by default `bc` works with integer math). 16 is probably far more than you need for a percentage, especially after multiplying by 100. Experiment until you get what you like.

** other thought **  I think that `awk` is a MUCH better tool for this. I don't have `svmon` available on my machine (Mac OS) but based on what you wrote I think I can figure out that it produces multiple lines, one of which has the word `memory` in it. And you want to compute the ratio of two fields (it seems you divide field 3 by field 2). In awk that would be:

```
svmon -G | awk '{if($0 ~ /memory/) {printf("memory used: %.1f%%\n", 100.0 * $3 / $2)}}'
```

I think it is much more compact... you may need to tweak it - I'm not sure I got the field numbers right. As I said, I don't have `svmon`.

**one more update**

To get the result in a shell variable, you can take your entire command and wrap it in a `$()` construct, like so:

```
memPct=$(echo "scale=1; 100 * " $(svmon -G | grep memory | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f 3)/$(svmon -G | grep memory | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f 2) | bc)
echo $memPct "%"
```

will put the percentage in the shell variable `$memPct`, then print it out with a `%` sign after it...

Note - it is important that you don't have any spaces in the first part of this command or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Floris. It's working.Also Could please educate me on how to multiply the above result with 100 in the same line?

Comment: @Althaf - I have updated the answer; you just add `100 *` in the first part of the `echo` command! This is because `bc` will evaluate the mathematical expression you feed it; so if you feed it `100 * 5 / 8` that is what it will compute.

Comment: I got it. Now I am getting the output as expected.  Thanks A lot Floris. Have a nice day

Comment: You're welcome. I just added another option too - see if you like that better. It certainly is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Floris. I'm good with first option. I am facing one more problem here in Storing the calculated value to variable. Could you please help me on this as well.

Comment: In general, when you use `bash` you can wrap any command inside `$()` and use that in another expression. So `a=$(echo 100 / 3 | bc)` results in the variable `$a` being set to `33`... Can you take it from there? Note - no space between `a` and `=`...

Comment: @Althaf - what do you mean by "unexpected value"? I updated my answer with something that should work.

Comment: @Althaf - I just noticed you had tried to edit my answer to show your 'unexpected value'. You did not include the `scale = 16;` part of the command that I had given in my original answer. Since `bc` will use integer math where possible, the order matters. `100 * 3 / 4` will result in `75` (order: (3*100) = 300; 300 / 4 = 75) , but `3 / 4 * 100` will result in `0` (order: (3/4) = 0; 0 * 100 = 0) since `3/4` is zero when you don't keep track of the fraction.  So either fix the order (put `100*` in front) or include `scale=` with some sensible number (2, if you want whole percent only).

Comment: Thanks a lot Floris & Henk for all your help & suggestions here. Now Everything looks good my script.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier in `awk`, `nawk`* or `mawk`:

```
svmon() { [[ $1 == -G ]] || return

echo memory 7864320 4915483 junk
echo foo bar baz
echo

}   

test_it() {
    svmon -G | nawk '/memory/ {
        print $3 / $2; exit
    }'
} && test_it
```

*This sample includes a mock function for those of us without svmon. The actual solution is in the three lines of code in the function `test_it`*

```
test_it() {
    svmon -G | nawk -v OFMT="%.12f" '/memory/ {
        print $3 / $2; exit
    }'
} && test_it
```

*Increase precision with OFMT, see nawk(1)*

---

> *
>    `nawk` is *New Awk*, also sometimes called the 'one true awk'. It's the 1985 revision of the 1977 original *[awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)* (after that named `oawk`).  *Nawk* is the basic reference for the language and its features have been adopted by many others.

Comment: +1 for including a mock function "for those of us without svmon". Might want to add `100*` to show percentage (as asked). Agree that `awk` is the better tool for this, but gave both options (pipe into `bc` or use `awk`) in my answer to educate OP. Not familiar with `nawk` I must admit.

Comment: Thanks for the response Henk...I have been asked to stick with the code which I've written in the main post. Could you please help me in storing the same output to variable ?

Comment: @Floris, nawk is the name the AT&T AST group gave to the reference implementation back in 1985, and the book from 1988. Unix vendors typically ship *nawk* as `awk`.  For linux, `awk` used to be *gawk* or *mawk*. See also [wikipedia on awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

Comment: @HenkLangeveld - thanks for the link. All this time I never knew I was using `nawk`...